# Inject a datasource using jrs-rest-java-client to a report

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using JasperReports Server with its [jrs-rest-java-client API](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client). When I access the remote server I want to inject the datasource (in my case it is a database) that the report should use. I do not know if it is possible to do it using this API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. This is how I do it in JasperReports Server v6.2.1 with the jrs-rest-java-client v6.2.3:

```
// build configuration object
RestClientConfiguration configuration = new RestClientConfiguration("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver");
configuration.setContentMimeType(MimeType.JSON);
configuration.setAcceptMimeType(MimeType.JSON);
configuration.setAuthenticationType(AuthenticationType.SPRING);
configuration.setLogHttp(true);
configuration.setLogHttpEntity(true);

// build client and authenticate
JasperserverRestClient client = new JasperserverRestClient(configuration);
Session session = client.authenticate("jasperadmin", "jasperadmin");

String reportUnitUri = "/path/to/reportUnit";

// first get the version of the reportUnit to prevent update conflicts from optimistic locking
OperationResult<ClientReportUnit> reportUnitOperationResult = session.resourcesService().resource(reportUnitUri).get(ClientReportUnit.class);
Integer reportUnitVersion = reportUnitOperationResult.getEntity().getVersion();

// build patchDescriptor with the dataSource field
PatchDescriptor patchDescriptor = new PatchDescriptor();
patchDescriptor.setVersion(reportUnitVersion);
patchDescriptor.field("dataSource", "/path/to/repository/dataSource");

// apply the patchDescriptor
session.resourcesService().resource(reportUnitUri).patchResource(ClientReportUnit.class, patchDescriptor);
```