# How can I set the data adapter when running a report via the rest 2 API

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using Jasper Server 6.3 Community Edition. I have a set of reports that I want to be able to execute against different databases. I have a data adapter defined for each database. I want to be able to execute any of these reports via the rest 2 API and just tell it to use a different data adapter.

The piece of XML that is pertinent to this setting in the jrxml is:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="common\test.xml"/>
```

The ideal situation would be, to be able to pass any value I want to replace `common\test.xml`

From what I can tell though, there is no built in parameter to set the data adapter, and one cannot use a parameter to set this either. In other words this won't work:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="$P!{data_adapter_path}"/>
```

So how can the `net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter` value be set dynamically using the rest 2 API?

Comment: Are you tied to the version 6.3 of the JasperReports Server?

Comment: No, I can go up in version, but I want to stick to community edition.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to upgrade to at least JasperReports Server 6.4.0 where you could use a `propertyExpression` instead of `property`, like so (I am posting only the relevant fragment):

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter"><![CDATA[$P{DataAdapterLocation}]]></propertyExpression>
<parameter name="DataAdapterLocation" class="java.lang.String" evaluationTime="Early">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["default/path/to/DataAdapterFile"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

The `evaluationTime="Early"` on the parameter is essential for this to work.

Another but complex solution, that would not require an upgrade, would involve creating JDBC Data Sources(via [interface](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-community-project-administrator-guide/v640/jdbc-data) or REST API) and assigning them to the appropriate Report Unit. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170262/inject-a-datasource-using-jrs-rest-java-client-to-a-report/38200479#38200479) shows how you could achieve that by using the [jrs-rest-java-client](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jrs-rest-java-client) .